# How to detect collinearity in ivreg and extract their causal variables of its data frame used?

Tags: r

I'm running an ivreg, but my matrix of data is singular because of multicollinearity. I'd like to extract the variables that cause collinearity and execute ivreg again. I've tried with VIF (it didn't work), ALIAS (it only detects columns that cause collinearity but it can not work for ivreg),...

I decided to make a function that does the process I want with condition number. It's next:

```
`estikappa<-function(reg,formula,data,crv,...){(if(kappa(reg)>crv)
{if(is.null(alias(reg)$Complete)==T)
{reg<-lm(formula,data)return(reg)}else{ld.vars<-attributes(alias(reg)$Complete)$dimnames[[1]]
 formulan<-as.formula(paste(paste(deparse(formula),collapse = ""),
paste(ld.vars,collapse = "-"),
 sep="-"))
regn<-lm(formulan,data)
reg<-regn
return(reg)}})
(if(kappa(reg)<-crv){reg<-lm(formula,data)
return(reg)})
}`
```

Unfortunately, estikappa() only works with lm, not with "ivreg" class. Therefore, I tried to do 2SLS by hand (typing), but the "Betas" of second stage and ivreg() are differents for one reason that I've couldn't figure out. Hence, I decided to find an alternative method to extract the variables that cause multicollinearity, but I've not been lucky.

Any help I'll be extremely grateful.